# Can I force Linux to initialise a PCI-Express card that the BIOS does not support/recognise?

Tags: linux, boot, motherboard, bios, linux-kernel

I'm trying to get a PCI-Express 1.0 1x TV tuner card ([TBS 6280](https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/TBS6280)) to work in a Dell PowerEdge T110 II.

I've confirmed from sources such as [here](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-Hardware-General/PowerEdge-T110-II-PCIe-1x-cards-not-detected-by-Bios/td-p/3873312) that the BIOS does not support older TBS tuner cards, possibly due to them using PCI-e 1.0a spec.

There is nothing at all related to the card output in dmesg or lspci, but I can see it is plugged in via dmidecode:

```
Handle 0x0021, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: PCIE4
        Type: x1 PCI Express 2 x1
        Current Usage: In Use
        Length: Long
        ID: 4
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                Opening is shared
                PME signal is supported
                Hot-plug devices are supported
        Bus Address: 0000:00:00.0
```

Is there any way to force the kernel to give this card a bus address and/or initialise it?

Answer (score 0):

The website [LinuxTV.org](https://linuxtv.org/)
has
[complete instructions for the TBS6280](https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/TBS6280).

It also describes the
[TBS driver installation](https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/TBS_driver_installation).

The latest build instructions for the driver are to be found on the page of
[github linux_media](https://github.com/tbsdtv/linux_media/wiki).

The information supplied is too detailed to be reproduced here.

Making the drive visible in `lspci` is described on the same website
in the post
[Installed drivers but card not in "lspci"](https://www.tbsdtv.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=9738):

> I solved this by updating my motherboard BIOS to the newest version, and then in the BIOS setting the PCIe mode to "GEN1". That last bit is essential!

Comment: Seeing how `lspci` does not list the card, these instructions will not help.

Comment: @DanielB: Added advice for that as well. There is of course no guarantee that this will work for the poster's firmware/hardware.

Comment: Therein lies the problem I'm afraid, the motherboard does not support 'GEN1' (1.0a) PCI express and there is no option or BIOS update to enable it. Dell's opinion on the matter seems to be that you're on your own when it comes to PCI cards except for a certified subset

Comment: I can see a very recent BIOS update [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/lu/en/lubsd1/product-support/product/poweredge-t110-2/drivers), if this is your model.

Comment: Aye I was surprised to see such a recent update for an old server, but no joy with that unfortunately

Comment: Do you have in the BIOS anything resembling "PCIe mode", and if so, what are its possible values?